# Why the execution time of parallel problem is better for an odd number of threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I implemented in parallel an algorithm which finds and prints all the circular prime numbers within the interval [2, X]. I measured the execution time of the problem varying the number of threads from 1 to 16. Can someone explain why I get worse execution time when the number of threads is even? (Note: actually I get worse time for an odd number of threads if the main thread is also taken into account)

The processor of the machine I ran the program is "Intel® Core™ i7-8550U", with 4 cores and hyperthreading.

This is the function which the threads are executing (I performed load balancing):

```
void *printIfCircularPrime(void *threadId)
{
    int tid = (int)threadId;
    printf("Hi, I am thread %d\n", threadId);

    for (long i = 2 + tid; i <= X; i += NR_THREADS)
    {
        if (isCircularPrime(i))
        {
            printf("%ld\n", i);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

These are my execution time measurements:

[image]

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NR_THREADS 16
#define X 120000000

int isPrime(long n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }   
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int d = 3; d <= floor(sqrt(n)); d += 2)
    {
        if (n % d == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int countDigits(long n)
{
    int digits = 0;
    while (n)
    {
        n /= 10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
}

long cyclicallyPermute(long n, int numberOfDigits)
{
    int lastDigit = n % 10;
    return pow(10, numberOfDigits - 1) * lastDigit + n / 10;
}

int isCircularPrime(long n)
{
    int numberOfDigits = countDigits(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++)
    {
        if (!isPrime(n))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        n = cyclicallyPermute(n, numberOfDigits);
    }
    return 1;
}

void *printIfCircularPrime(void *threadId)
{
    int tid = (int)threadId;
    printf("Hi, I am thread %d\n", threadId);

    for (long i = 2 + tid; i <= X; i += NR_THREADS)
    {
        if (isCircularPrime(i))
        {
            printf("%ld\n", i);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Number of threads: %d\n", NR_THREADS);
    pthread_t threads[NR_THREADS];

    struct timespec start, stop;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);

    for (int i = 0; i < NR_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, printIfCircularPrime, (void *)i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NR_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop);

    printf("\nExecution time: %ld seconds\n", stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Please post your circular prime algorithm and your benchmarking code. If you're using some sort of array to store intermediate values, you could be limited by memory bus bandwidth. Approx 4 threads can swamp the memory bus/cache so, eventually, you reach the law of diminishing returns. It can highly depend of the specifics of the algorithm [and how it's implemented].

Comment: How many times did you run your tests for each threads number?

Comment: Too much code is missing here

Comment: I posted the full code. I only ran the tests 2-3 times for each case

Comment: I'd also wonder how much time is spent in `printf("%ld\n", i);`.  and what affect that code has on the result.

Comment: The only even prime is 2. So when `tid` and `NR_THREADS` are both even, the thread is totally useless.

Comment: There are not a lot of circular prime numbers (999331 is the biggest one smaller than my X). The program finishes printing them in less than 1 second. It spends the rest of the time processing the remaining numbers.

Comment: @user3386109 Yeah, you are right. The even threads will finish faster and the main will wait more for the odd ones (which actually do the entire work)

Comment: Note also that there is no point in using more computational threads than you have cores to run them on, at least if you are distributing the work (relatively) evenly.